# Order by version number in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, version

I have several rows with the following update versions:

```
2022.20.10
2022.24.6
2022.24.5
2022.24.1
2022.20.9
2022.20.8
2020.39.104.2.1
2022.3.103.0.1
```

How can these be ordered using the standard ORDER BY option in the query?
I've attempted to use the ip address function but it doesn't work for these versions.

Desired result:

```
2022.24.6
2022.24.5
2022.24.1
2022.20.10
2022.20.9
2022.20.8
2022.3.103.0.1
2020.39.104.2.1
```

Comment: Is that a badly stored/formatted date?

Comment: Either extract each part and sort by it or normalize the values with leading zeros.

Comment: Or use `ORDER BY INET_ATON(INSERT(tablename.versioncolumn, 3, 0, '.'))`

Comment: Do these values correspond to dates?

Comment: It's a version number, and isn't directly related to the date. Thank you 
Akina but that doesn't quite work, throws lots of random results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just formulating [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina)'s as a Community Wiki, as his solution works perfectly as intended. You can use the following ORDER BY clause:

```sql
ORDER BY INET_ATON(INSERT(tablename.versioncolumn, 3, 0, '.'))
```

Of course you'll have to replace `tablename` and `versioncolumn` with the correct values. A working DB fiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDhsWrS2xmesiPpdhzHamf/1).